# What is the relationship between a requirement for consistency of a theory and what it can prove?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

This is a question that I always had in mind.

When it is said that the consistency of a theory $T$ *requires* the assumption of existence of some specified cardinal $\kappa$. Is that taken to mean that $T$ can prove the existence of all cardinals strictly smaller than $\kappa$?

A clarifying example, suppose its said that a theory $T$ requires existence of $0^\sharp$, one might get the impression that $T$ can interpret each theory ZFC+ $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is a cardinal property such that ZFC + $\kappa$ is interpretable in ZFC+$0^\sharp$. So viewing the list of [large cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_large_cardinal_properties) properties, then one would for example expect that $T$ can interpret ZFC+ Mahlo cardinal exist. Is that impression correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where there is a fair amount of abuse of language, unfortunately.

Generally statements like this are shorthand for a consistency strength claim over the base theory ZFC; e.g. when people say "X requires a measurable cardinal" what is meant is that ZFC+"There is a measurable cardinal" is consistent relative to ZFC+X (even more formally, that PRA proves "If ZFC+X is consistent, then ZFC+"There is a measurable cardinal" is consistent).

Sometimes a different base theory on one or the other side is meant; e.g. "AD requires a measurable" means that ZF+AD is consistent only if ZFC+"There is a measurable" is, and this is clear from context since ZFC+AD is outright inconsistent.

Note that this is all *strictly weaker* than saying that the large cardinal actually needs to exist; when we say that X requires a measurable cardinal we generally do *not* mean that ZFC proves "If X, then there is a measurable cardinal." In particular, there's a huge difference between "There is a measurable cardinal" and "There is **an inner model with** a measurable cardinal."

(Incidentally, it's not even clear to me what "$T$ can prove the existence of all cardinals strictly smaller than $\kappa$?" would mean in the first place.)

Comment: I've added a clarifying example addressing the last two lines of your answer.

Comment: I think the implications in your answer are the converse. I mean if I say that X requires measurable cardinal then its taken to mean that PRA proves that if ZFC+measurable cardinal is consistent, then ZFC+X is consistent.

Comment: @Zuhair **Absolutely not** - under that reading, "$2+2=4$" would require a measurable! "Requires" is analogous to "only if."

Comment: I wouldn't call it abuse of language. It is standard jargon.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Oh yes of course, I was confused, I thought its the least cardinal in that direction. Anyhow i think its equivalent to the direction you've stated.